# Want user input of exactly "(x,y)" Including parentheses and comma

Tags: matlab

What I currently have produces an error.
Essentially I need to have the exact input "(x,y)" and then store the x in an array and the y in an array. I am just having trouble going from (x,y) input to storing x in its array and y in its array.

I want the user to enter n points, where they specify n
Example:

User wants 2 points
They enter:
 (1,2)
 (2,5)

My teacher wants the input to be exactly (x,y).     Including parentheses and comma. I will be fine once I can get x and y to their respective arrays.

---

```
strAskN = "Enter the number of data points to be entered. ";
disp(strAskN);
n = countRequest();

strAskCoordA = ('Enter the coordinate pair (x,y) in scientific '); 
strAskCoordB = ('notaion with 5 significant figures.');
disp (strcat(strAskCoordA,strAskCoordB));
for i = 1:n
    z = input('Enter Coordinate: ');
    a(i) = z;
end

function n = countRequest()
   n = input(' ');
end
```

---

Output:

---

```
>> Enter the number of data points to be entered. 
 2
>> Enter the coordinate pair (x,y) in scientific notaion with 5 significant figures.
>> Enter Coordinate: (2,3)
Error using Assignment5 (line 16)
Error: Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.
```

---

Line 16 is the line `z = input('Enter Coordinate: ');`

---

I am not sure why it will not allow a string with (x,y). I assume either the parentheses or comma messes it up. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force MATLAB to return the input as it is as a char array with with flag `s` in [`input()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) but I recommend to cast it to a string immediately to avoid problems with assigning it to the variable later

```
z = input('Enter Coordinate: ','s');
a(i) = string(z)
```

This is because a sting has always the dimension 1x1, while the same char-array may have the dimension 4x1. Note that you can allocate your string array before the loop with `a = strings(n,1)`.

Now back to your problem: The error is that you entered `(x,y)` and not `"(x,y)"` or `'(x,y)'` as suggested by your title. MATLAB tries to *evaluate* the expression, which is typed for input, so if ou type an invalid expressen (which most starting with a `(` is), it raises an error telling you that `()` is for functions or mathematical expressions only

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed.