# Matlab input coordinates in form '(x,y)'

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I need to prompt user to input coordinates exactly in the form '(x,y)' where x is the x value and y is the y value for a coordinate pair. The user must also type in the parentheses (can't use the brackets). How do i do this??? Thanks

Comment: Try [splitting](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) the input with `,` as delimiter and [covert to double](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605255/want-user-input-of-exactly-x-y-including-parentheses-and-comma/61606592#61606592). If it is the same task, you'll find the answer =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want user input of exactly "(x,y)" Including parentheses and comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605255/want-user-input-of-exactly-x-y-including-parentheses-and-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Try designing a regex that matches exactly the input form you're looking for, and then using `regexp()` on the user's input to see if it matches that regex. If it matches, the input is good; if it doesn't match, you reject the input and prompt again.